# ROS1 Noetic does not run rqt_graph on windows 10

Tags: ros, rqt-graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had similar problem as this [question here](https://answers.ros.org/question/361088/rqt_graph-not-working-on-windows-10/)

[I installed ROS 1 noetic on windows 10 natively (no wsl2)](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows)
Although I have used VS 2022, it should work as VS 2019, right?

[But when I reach the tutorial "Understanding ROS Topics](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics) I get the error below and my rqt_graph shows empty:

```
PluginHandlerDirect._restore_settings() plugin "rqt_graph/RosGraph#0" raised an exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1914, in create
    stdout_data, stderr_data, process = call_graphviz(
  File "c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 129, in call_graphviz
    process = subprocess.Popen(
  File "subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\lib\site-packages\qt_gui\plugin_handler_direct.py", line 121, in _restore_settings
    self._plugin.restore_settings(plugin_settings_plugin, instance_settings_plugin)
  File "c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\lib\site-packages\rqt_graph\ros_graph.py", line 260, in restore_settings
    self._refresh_rosgraph()
  File "c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\lib\site-packages\rqt_graph\ros_graph.py", line 289, in _refresh_rosgraph
    self._update_graph_view(self._generate_dotcode())
  File "c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\lib\site-packages\rqt_graph\ros_graph.py", line 308, in _generate_dotcode
    return self.dotcode_generator.generate_dotcode(
  File "c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\lib\site-packages\rqt_graph\dotcode.py", line 914, in generate_dotcode
    dotcode = dotcode_factory.create_dot(dotgraph)
  File "c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\lib\site-packages\qt_dotgraph\pydotfactory.py", line 175, in create_dot
    dot = graph.create_dot()
  File "c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1722, in new_method
    return self.create(
  File "c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1924, in create
    raise OSError(*args)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] "dot" not found in path.
```

[Additionally when i "solved this" the graph will show, but the icon did not show and the fonts are pixelated rather than smooth.](https://www.programmersought.com/article/2969856002/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393714/ros1-noetic-does-not-run-rqt_graph-on-windows-10/) by [zain0097](https://answers.ros.org/users/92780/zain0097/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2022-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @zain0097, I don't think assuming VS 2022 will behave the same as VS 2019.

You could setup your VS 2022 to compile only with VS 2019 components but that will be outside the scope of this forum, that's one way to work around it.

What I could tell you is that the process works fairly smooth with VS 2019, so I recommend if you can to install with VS 2019. If you have no other choice but to use VS 2022, then I recommend to raise the issue here: https://github.com/ms-iot/ROSOnWindows/issues

But since it's not a supported configuration, how much support you will get.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zain0097](https://answers.ros.org/users/92780/zain0097/) on 2022-01-13**:
I reinstalled ROS and with 2022 and it worked perfectly fine, except the rqt graph is pixlated and some icons are missing. The text do show, but not icons

**Comment by [zain0097](https://answers.ros.org/users/92780/zain0097/) on 2022-01-13**:
I also tried with VS 2019 and got same thing.